# C# WPF - Adding an image to a dataset or datagrid - code behind only

Tags: c#, wpf, image, datagrid, dataset

I have a datagrid which is defined at the beginning

```
 DataGrid dtgWatch;
```

and linked to a Dataset dtsWatch;

```
dtgWatch.ItemsSource = dtsWatch.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

in the middle the dataset is filled with rows with

```
 dtsWatch.Tables[0].Rows.Add(string1, string2);
```

The purpose is something like the following tab:

> | string1_A     |     string2_A |
>
> | string1_B     |     string2_B |
>
> | string1_B     |     string2_C |

that works properly.
Now the change: at a point of that reasoning (and only for one row) I have to put an image and not a string.
That means:

> | string1_A     |     string2_A |
>
> | string1_B     |     Image2_B  | <---------------
>
> | string1_B     |     string2_C |

Theoretically speaking this should work (no compilation error) for in case of the image I am adding the line with

```
Image img =...
dtsWatch.Tables[0].Rows.Add(string1, img);
```

but the result is

> | string1     |     System.Windows.Controls.Image |

---

A possible solution I have thought of is to put a marker somewhere and then at the runtime (Loading row event or something like that) to change the content of the cell with the image. Unfortunately I could do that for I could get to directly access and modify the cell.

---

I am doing all that with C# wpf with the appdomain tecnique. That means that I have not xaml, I have to do everything in code behind. All what I have is a grid to add with the datagrid.

---

I have tried [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13531327/adding-image-do-datagrid-programically-in-c-sharp-wpf-project-how) but it is not completed and all the other solutions I found were implying the use of a xaml

---

Thanks for any help

Patrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I have followed a different approach:

```
private void Dg_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dg.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < dg.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            TextBlock cellContent = dg.Columns[j].GetCellContent(row) as TextBlock;
            var strContent = cellContent.Text;
            if (strContent == "BBB2")
            {
                    // This if I want merely change the value (not my case)
                    //cellContent.Text = "XXXX";

                    //This if I want to put an image
                    var dtgCell = cellContent.Parent as DataGridCell;
                    dtgCell.Content = new Image() { Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Users\Pictures\Ball_Red.png")) };
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So instead trying to modify the dtg BEFORE showing it, I change it AFTER.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the desired behaviour you have to create your DataGridColumns manually.

You can still write Xaml, because you can easily parse and create the corresponding objects in code behind.
See [`System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.load?view=netframework-4.7.2)

So this should work for you

```
dtgWatch.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
foreach (DataColumn column in dtsWatch.Tables[0].Columns)
{
    string dataGridTemplateColumn = $@"
    <DataGridTemplateColumn
        Header=""{column.ColumnName}""
        xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation""
        xmlns:x=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"" >
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentControl Content=""{{Binding {column.ColumnName}}}"" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>";
    XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(dataGridTemplateColumn));
    dtgWatch.Columns.Add((DataGridTemplateColumn)System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(xr)); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint and sorry for being late... that solution is very promising moreover for it is teaching me a new tecnique. That said, picture me dumb but I can understand how that works. I'll make it clear: the same column sometimes has to store a string and sometimes has to store an image. Let's make an example:         Row1: col1=Val1a col2=Val1b     Row2: col1:val1  col2= ...image from file system... could you please provide me with a practical example? Thanks

Comment: Sorry  I have found a different road. Thanks however for your help